# XSLT: How to replace some XML element names by other

Tags: xml, xslt

For example this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<products>
 <product>
   <code>37</code>
   <ws_code>T37</ws_code>
   <barcode>11111111</barcode>
 </product>
</products>
```

I want to change it to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<products>
 <product>
   <ProductCode>37</ProductCode>
   <ProductBarcode>11111111</ProductBarcode>
 </product>
</products>
```

I am working on an XSLT file (there are missing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product/code">
        <ProductCode><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></ProductCode>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product/barcode">
        <ProductBarcode><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></ProductBarcode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually, the XML file comes over the server and I cannot make any changes to this file.

How can I change these element names and delete some tags using XSLT and how can I link XSLT and XML files?

The tag names to change are:

> code    --> ProductCode
>   ws_code --> Should be deleted
>   barcode --> ProductBarcode

Comment: It's great that you've provided a clear example of the input XML and the output you would like. Could you also post the XSLT you have tried so far?

Comment: `code-->ProductCode` translates into `<xsl:template match="code"><ProductCode><xsl:apply-templates/></ProductCode></xsl:template>`, deleting `ws_code` into `<xsl:template match="ws_code"/>`, then add the identity transformation template and implement other necessary changes with additional templates following that approach.

Comment: I added an example of my xslt file to the question. But I do not know how to connect my xslt file to xml.

Comment: @D.Dirik "*I do not know how to connect my xslt file to xml.*" That depends on what will you be using to perform the transformation.

Comment: @BenL I added my xslt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT is pretty close to what you want, just it is not removing the `ws_code` element and could be a bit simpler.

To remove the `ws_code` element, create a template that matches it to do nothing.

Given your input XML, you don't need to match `product/code` or `product/barcode`. Just `code` and `barcode` will match those elements.

You can use `<apply-templates/>` rather than `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` in your template matches. This will process all children of the current node: see [Applying Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules).

By using `*|@*` in the identity template instead of `node()|@*`, it won't match text nodes and so the whitespace between elements won't be output. The text underneath `code` and `barcode` is still output by virtue of the [built-in Template Rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) for text nodes.

The XSLT below achieves what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code">
    <ProductCode>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ProductCode>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="barcode">
    <ProductBarCode>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ProductBarCode>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ws_code"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Applying the following XSLT-1.0 file (I named it `d.xslt`) to your above input XML file (I named it `d.xml`(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ws_code[local-name(..) = 'product']" />

    <xsl:template match="product/code">
        <ProductCode><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></ProductCode>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product/barcode">
        <ProductBarcode><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></ProductBarcode>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested this with the following command/XSLTProcessor on Linux/Ubuntu:

```
xsltproc d.xslt d.xml | xmlindent -f -nbe
```

and the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <ProductCode>37</ProductCode>
        <ProductBarcode>11111111</ProductBarcode>
    </product>
</products>
```

as desired.

This XSLT code does replace `code` and `barcode` elements which have a `product` node as a parent with `ProductCode` and `ProductBarcode` elements respectively. `ws_code` nodes are ignored and the ignored *spaces* are eliminated by the `<xsl:strip-space...>`.

Comment: I see no need to limit the match by referring to the parent. And I certainly see no need to refer to the parent so obliquely: if you really want to match only `code` whose parent is `product` say either `product/code` or `code[parent::product]`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I changed my answer according to one of your suggestions, but, however, many ways do lead to Rome.

Comment: But some ways are bad practice. There is no justification to refer to an element by its local name, unless you do not know in what namespace it is. That is extremely rare - and when it happens, you're in danger of getting a false positive from another element with the same local name, but in another namespace.